# Java. Resize issue on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout

The following code snippet allows me to place a JTextfield and 2 JButtons on a JPanel using BorderLayout Manager.

```
        JPanel strPanel = new ButtonPanel();
        strPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBorder( new EmptyBorder( 3, 3, 3, 3 ) );

        strfield = new JTextField("",70);
        strPanel.add("West", strfield);
        strPanel.add("Center", btnCopy);
        strPanel.add("East", btnPaste);
        add("North", strPanel);
```

Here is a screenshot

[image]

However, the kicker is that when I resize my JFrame the 'copy' button is enlarged but I would like the JTextField to be enlarged instead with the copy and paste buttons remaining the same size.  Here is an updated screenshot:

[image]

To try and fix it I downloaded NetBeans etc and played with the GUI designer but I can't solve it, even using different layout managers.

Can someone shed some light?  Thanks

Comment: @Wug It is if you know how to use it.

Comment: I know how to use it just fine, but I still don't like it.

Comment: @Wug It's definitely not the best option in the programming world, but it is very powerful. Reading that comment, I came off as harsh and that wasn't my intention. I was just trying to point out that swing can do just about anything you need if you know the right tricks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BorderLayout` isn't cut out for this task since it gives all the left over space to the `CENTER` component. If you can change layout to `GridBagLayout` it's simple to give the leftmost component all the left over space.

### Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;

    frame.add(new JTextArea("Hello World!"), gbc);

    gbc.weightx = 0;
    frame.add(new JButton("Copy"), gbc);
    frame.add(new JButton("Paste"), gbc);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

---

If you really want to use `BorderLayout`, you can group the buttons together and add them to the east, adding the text field to the center, do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    frame.add(new JTextArea("Hello World!"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0)) {{
        add(new JButton("Copy"));
        add(new JButton("Paste"));
    }}, BorderLayout.EAST);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: Thanks dacwe for that really quick and informative response!!  Working now.  For simplicity I have stuck with BorderLayout but Gridbag is the way to go.  Cheers

Comment: Update.  Implemented the Gridbag approach - more flexible and scalable.  Again, cheers!!

Comment: Great :-) It's hard to know which layout to choose in what situation. Read about them all and it will be easier to get the "best" one.